How to create EtherChannel / Link aggregation between two HP switches - on dissimilar port speed
I have the following network architecture between 2x HP 5900 switches located about 2kms apart
Switch 1 ----2 kms ------ Switch 2
Laser Link 10G <---------- > Laser Link 10G
MW link 150M <-----------> Microwave link 150M
The laser link flaps due to issues with vibrations with the pole - I have link-delay enabled to prevent flapping - but the user experience is not great
The Laser link provides 10G - but when there are gusts of wind the user can experience occasional disconnections - You can say that the laser link is available for about 98% of the time i.e. about 30 minutes of 'downtime' in a day - this downtime is split up into several blocks of 'drops' lasting from a couple of 100's of ms to couple of seconds
The client also has a MW which gives around 150Mbits/sec, make is CPE710 from TP Link
How can I configure port trunking / Etherchanel Aggregation on the two ports - this is to ensure that the user experience is not impacted due to the occasional high packet loss on the laser link
Is it even possible - what are the configurations I can try ?

That will actually cause more problems than you have now.

Is the laser link state actually indicating down or are there just short periods of packet loss?

@Zac67 since I have carrier-delay enabled the prt is not coming down by state - but yes the actual physical link does come down occasionally for a few 100's of ms to few seconds - the problem is that users are running some type of application that keeps getting disconnected / logged out

LACP does not support mismatched port speeds. And it wouldn't help if it did. Ethernet is not a reliable transport - it does not detect or care about drops, so even with two paths, a frame that gets lost is gone for good; you'll have to wait for L3 to detect the drop and retransmit.
You need something that can detect the failure of the laser link and immediately switch traffic to the MW link. I'm not familiar with any fast failover mechanisms. LACP can do it, but it's not that fast.

An oscillating pole is a serious construction flaw for a laser link. There's only so much you can do on the network side. Neither LACP nor RSTP/MSTP nor anything else based on link status is fast enough to cope with sub-second link drops. Most link aggregation protocols lack support for mixed-rate links in general, further complicating that approach.
Some suggestions, in descending order of preference:

Fix the pole so that it doesn't oscillate any more. Some guy wire might work wonders.
Use actively stabilized laser optics.
Use policy-based routing to run sensitive, yet low-bandwidth applications on the reliable microwave link, and keep high-bandwidth but hopefully robust applications on the faster laser link.

